# PowerShell doesn't return error running executable

Tags: powershell, ssis, executable

I have a problem with a PowerShell script that is executed with an execute process task. The executable generates an error that needs to be returned to SSIS resulting in package failure.

The settings in my process task are following:

[image]

My PowerShell code has a try an catch. So normally a (fatal) error should be caught. The Finally block returns the correct exit code to SSIS (this works, if I put 1 in both blocks the package fails).

```
Try
{

    $program = "Y:\Program Files (x86)\VMMa\Process Add Txt\MP_Add_txt.exe"
    #edited lines to capture the error
    $e = Start-Process -FilePath "$program" -wait -passthru
    if ($e.exitcode -ne 0) {
    write-error "I failed with error $($e.exitcode)";
    $err1 = 1;
    }
    #end edit
}
Catch
{
    #Write-Host "Error in function";
    $err1 = 1;
}
Finally
#{Write-Output $err1 }
{
    if($err1 -eq 1)
    {
        ## - Custom Exit Code:
        [Environment]::Exit("1");
    }
    Else
    {
        #Write-Output $result;
        [Environment]::Exit("0");
    }
}
```

The error that is generated during the run:

[image]

SSIS marks the task as succesful. The problem is my PowerShell code I guess because the final block is working. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Capture the exit code from `Start-Process`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this indeed solved my problem. Just for informative reasons I updated the corrected code (for anyone using SSIS)